# Don't display all record by default in odoo tree view

Tags: python, xml, odoo

In Odoo (openERP) the default behavior for Tree view to list all items with pagination.

Is there any possible way to not list any records by default and list when searched through search-bar or advanced search?

Comment: Possibly, but I don't know what do you want it to be, or what do you mean _by default_?

Comment: I don't want items to be listed unless i do search on them. So the list view is not listing all items (records).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating wizard and then after closing that wizard you can get all your data. Create a menu, in its action just give a view id of your wizard. From wizard get all argument from user and then after successfully getting that data generate dynamic view from py.

Answer (score 1):

I figured a possible solution not set Auto search in action windows to False.

[image]